# Release memory after loading PDF in API

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core, memory-leaks

I have a ASP .NET Core 3.0 API app that returns a PDF file of a WPF page. It generates the WPF page itself and then converts it to XPS  so i can then convert it to PDF but when its done loading the api doesnt release it from memory so it just builds up until it crashes. I have implemented GC.collect for each time it has generated a PDF but with no real success.

[image: memory usage after loading a few PDF files]

Class i use to generate the PDF from a WPF app with IDispossable

```cs
public QueryAndGenerate(int orderNumber, string XPSPath, string PDFPath, bool throwExceptions = true)
{
    Helper.Log("QueryAndGenerate start");

    this.XPSPath = XPSPath;
    this.PDFPath = PDFPath;

    List<byte[]> Bytes = new List<byte[]>();

    var rows = QueryAndGenerate.GetDataRows(Properties.Resources.joborderQuery, new QueryAndGenerate.MySqlParameter("ORDERNUMBER", orderNumber));
    PDFPaths = new List<string>();
    Helper.Log(string.Format("rows from query: {0} lenth: {1}", rows, rows.Count));
    try
    {
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            isMultipleGuidenote = true;
            QueryAndGenerate queryAndGenerate = new QueryAndGenerate(orderNumber, row.Field<int>("JOBORDERNUMBER"), XPSPath, PDFPath, throwExceptions);
            Bytes.Add(File.ReadAllBytes(PDFPath));
            Helper.Log("generated file: "+ row);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Helper.Log(e);
    }

    PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
    foreach (byte[] pdfBytes in Bytes)
    {
        if (pdfBytes.Length != 0)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes))
            {
                PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open(stream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
                foreach (PdfPage page in inputDocument.Pages)
                {
                    outputDocument.AddPage(page);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    outputDocument.Save(this.PDFPath);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    xpsControls = null;
    jobRow = null;
    checkRows = null;
    warrantyRows = null;
    subAssemblyRows = null;
    detailRows = null;
    detailToolRows = null;
    detailItemRows = null;
    PDFPaths = null;
    cadmanCheck = null;
}
```

Comment: Do you dispose disposable instances?

Comment: Yes i do Dispose after each file has loaded

Comment: May we have a look at the code with that dispose?

Comment: I have edited the question, hope it clarifies it a bit better

Comment: If `PdfDocument`implement `IDosposable`, you need call `outputDocument.Dispose()` before `GC.Collect()`.

Comment: @Vernou I have added `outputDocument.Dispose();` but with no real result.

Comment: Isn't `inputDocument` also `IDisposable`? Dispose that one as well (`using(..)`). If that doesn't help, you can try checking memory usage at runtime or with a dump to understand which objects are piling up.

Comment: @lgoncalves you got any example of how to make a dump? i have never done it before

Comment: In Visual Studio, Debug -> Show Diagnostic Tools (Open Windows) -> (toggle) Memory Usage -> Take Snapshot. Take a snapshot before the call and after, and you can see the diff.

Comment: I think it might have something to do witht he WPF usercontrols not being released after loading but i cant figure out how to manualy release them.

Comment: you should almost never need to call GC.Collect in  production code; secondly just calling Collect is insufficient - google waitforpendingfinalizers.

Comment: So i have tweaked my code a bit but still have the issue, I have however installed dotMemory and noticed that everytime i load a PDF some ArrayList grows with 50 MB of memory. I think that this may be the cause but i have no clue how to now locate the ArrayList in question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are probably facing is fragmentation of the large object heap (LOH). The article [The Dangers of the Large Object Heap](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/) explains the problem very well. We faced the same issue in one of our REST-apis, which generates PDF files. The problem is, that the `byte[]` used is most likely larger than 85kb, which causes it to be placed in LOH. Your call to `GC.Collect();` initiates garbage collection on generation 0 of the heap. If you want to prevent this fragmentation from occuring, you should set GC-options before calling `GC.Collect();` as mentioned in [How to (not) use the large object heap in .Net](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3212988/how-to-not-use-the-large-object-heap-in-net.html) at [Getting rid of large object heap fragmentation](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3212988/how-to-not-use-the-large-object-heap-in-net.html#:%7E:text=Getting%20rid%20of%20large%20object%20heap%20fragmentation)

So basically replace your GC-calls with this:

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
GC.Collect(generation: 2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, blocking: true, compacting: true);
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect(generation: 2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, blocking: true, compacting: true);
```

Comment: In our scenario memory consumption was drastically reduced. I hope this helps with your issues.